# Segmented Control won't switch to the second container

Tags: swift, containers, uisegmentedcontrol

My code works for the two Container Views but when I run the simulator, the first view shows up and when I try to use the segmented control, my program crashes and returns the message

> Unrecognized selector sent to instance

My Code Below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var firstView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondView: UIView!
@IBAction func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex{
    case 0:
        //show info view
        firstView.isHidden = false
        secondView.isHidden = true
    case 1:
        //show list of service view
        firstView.isHidden = true
        secondView.isHidden = false
    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: It's likely because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45317576/7113238

Answer (score 0):

there may be problem of outlet or you have not connected method **segmentChanged** properly to the segmentControll For your reference please check this link https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/segmented-control-tutorial-ios8-swift